# Swap Fn and Ctrl keys on IdeaPad

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-10.10, lenovo-laptop

I just got a brand new IdeaPad G560 and installed Ubuntu 10.10 on it. Now I'd like to remap the fn key to control (I don't really care about remapping control to fn since I got another fn I use more). What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

On relatively recent ThinkPads, there's on option to swap them in the BIOS.  I'm not sure about IdeaPads, but it is worth having a look.

I personally find it no problem, and effortlessly swap between my ThinkPad and standard desktop keyboard.  You get used to it, but I have been doing this for years, and even earlier I got used to Ctrl and Alt being the other way around in CAD and graphics programs, when I used PowerMacs at work.

Comment: I'm already having problems switching between a Mac (with a mac keyboard) and stationary Linux (with a normal ctrl). Adding a third layout is not an option. And I checked the BIOS, there's nothing there. :-(